# How can i detect that the activity has been started

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, logcat

I am working on a Java Testing Controller Application that runs on a PC.
It does:

**Install app on the android phone:**

> adb install xxx.apk

**Start the activity:**

> adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName

**When activity has been started, send a broadcast:**

> send a broadcast to start the test function on the activity

Our app needs about a half minute to start, so, how can I detect if the app is ready?
I was thinking reading the logcat, but we have to test several devices at the same time.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: have you tried  onCreate?

Comment: a suggestion, setting a variable in shared prefs ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Debug Bridge (adb.exe) supports -s to issue/filter commands by device, e.g.

adb -s emulator-5554 logcat -c

will clear logcat for the device called emulator-5554.

Use:

adb devices

to list all devices running.

Maybe use "adb pull" and "adb push" to read/write a file. E.g. install app starts and writes some text to a file called flag.txt on the sd scard:

adb -s emulator-5554 pull /sdcard/flag.txt flag.txt

PC clears text and clears file for next run:

adb -s emulator-5554 push flag.txt /sdcard/flag.txt

Other ways may be possible, see adb docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Ok. Thanks! This works:  
  
> adb shell am start **-W** com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName  
  
**-W:** Wait for launch to complete.